# Thread communication: How to signal that a key was clicked? java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, conditional-statements

i have a simple JavaFX stage with a TextField. What i want to do is: when user inserts letters into the TextField, i want to print "now" (just to look if it works). Im using a Thread because later i want to scan a dictonary to see, if the letters the user entered are part of words from the dictionary.

But i get: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Any ideas? I don't seem to understand the whole concept of Condition.await and Multithreading..

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DictionaryThreading extends Application {


private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public static Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

private static class ScanWords implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try{    
            while(true){
                this.wait();
                System.out.println("clicked");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }   
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    new ScanWords().run();
    TextField tf = new TextField("Please enter a word");
    tf.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {});
    pane.getChildren().add(tf);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

}
```

Comment: I don't know quite anything about JavaFX. But I strongly believe that there should be some concept along "events" for doing exactly this.

Comment: You don't need to use threads to do this at all. Just use the usual event-handling approach (or, probably better and easier, just register a listener with the text field's [`textProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty).)

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm

Comment: An Example would be `btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
 
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        });`

Comment: But i want to scan a dictonary with over 100k words. That's why i wanted to use a Thread in background which scans the dictonary

Comment: Then you would launch a new thread *when* the text for which you are searching changes. You do not need a thread to wait for changes in the text.

Comment: One hint: rather avoid using "bare metal" threads. You might want to step back and see if you could be using abstractions like ExecutorService or such things.

Comment: You need to understand that UIs work event-based. So to say it unscientifically: The text will tell you when it changes. Then you can start some action upon that event. Same with quite everything in the UI. A button is clicked -> click event = the button notifies subscribers that it has been clicked. A TextField gets focus, .... many many things will cause events to fire.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you should not be using a Thread at all to observe changes in UI state.  However, for future reference, you are using Lock and `wait()` incorrectly here.  wait/notify are completely independent of Lock objects, and [wait() must always be called in a loop which checks a condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--);  Locks must be monitored by creating a Condition and using its await\* and signal\* methods.

Comment: FWIW I just wrote a quick test for scanning through a dictionary (with 350K words, represented as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)), and the vast majority of scans took just a few milliseconds. Scanning for all words (the worst case) is still less than 200ms. So it's arguably borderline whether you want to thread this at all.

Comment: Very interesting!!!! Thought this will last longer, but the fast scan time seems to be caused by the datastructure of the dictionary!? Can't imagine that scanning a txt file with 350k+ words is less then a second. Can you please post your dictionary? Would love to see it!!! Another question: if i would scan a txt-file, would you save the data temporaly in sth like a String array for faster scan? But this would exhaust RAM!? Or if you scan a full book: how would you do it? Read in the book an then scan or go through the book line by line without saving temporaly

Comment: I agree with James that if the scan is that fast, you need not necessarily spawn a thread. But in general, it is of course a good idea to not block the gui thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a thread that does nothing other than wait for user events. The JavaFX framework already provides this for you (it is one of the fundamental pieces of functionality of *any* UI toolkit). All you need to do to respond to changes in the text in a text field is register a change listener with the text field's text property:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    TextField tf = new TextField("Please enter a word");
    tf.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        System.out.println("text changed");
    });
    pane.getChildren().add(tf);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

If the thing you need to do in response to the text changing takes a long time, then you should launch that process in a background thread in the listener on the text field. If you are searching something large, you probably want to cancel any existing search, so that you don't end up with a large number of searches all running concurrently. The [JavaFX `Service` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) provides the functionality you need for this:

```
public class SearchService extends Service<List<String>> {

    // modify and access only on FX Application Thread:
    private String searchString ;

    @Override
    protected Task<List<String>> createTask() {
        final String s = searchString ;
        return new Task<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
                List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
                // do search for strings matching s
                // be sure to check isCancelled() regularly
                return matches ;
            }
        };
    }

    public String getSearchString() {
        checkThread();
        return searchString ;
    }

    public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
        checkThread();
        this.searchString = searchString ;
    }

    private void checkThread() {
        if (! Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not on FX Application Thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    SearchService searchService = new SearchService();

    searchService.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        List<String> matches = searchService.getValue();
        // do whatever you need with search results...
        // this is called on FX application thread
    });

    TextField tf = new TextField("Please enter a word");
    tf.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        searchService.cancel();
        searchService.setSearchText(newText);
        searchService.restart();
    });
    pane.getChildren().add(tf);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JavaFX, but I think you need to use `EventListener`. Try to use `TextListener` or `InputMethodListener`. For example:

```
StackPane pane = new StackPane();

TextField tf = new TextField("Please enter a word");

tf.addTextListener(e -> System.out.println("Pushed"));

pane.getChildren().add(tf);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

`wait` method should be executed within `synchronized` block:

```
    try{    
        while(true){
            synchronized(this){
                this.wait();
                System.out.println("clicked");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: It should not be used *at all* here!

Comment: It will prevent OP's issue from happening

Comment: Actually, I believe this is an X-Y-Problem. OP asks about the Monitor-State-Exception. But the actual issue is that he is doing things not in the correct way. So he shouldn't *have* that problem in the first place.

Comment: @IvanPronin This is not a correct solution to the problem, for three reasons. First, as already pointed out (and most importantly), there is no reason to create a thread waiting for user events: the framework already does that. Second, it doesn't really solve the problem, because you don't show how to release the "wait" when the user does something. And third, even if you were to implement this waiting thread, you should not use the low-level wait-notify structures, but a higher-level API, such as `Semaphore`.

Comment: So all I need to do is:-when keypressed --> Launch a thread which scans dictionary?

Comment: @jaaBeg16 That's quite it. Mind that there probably are tools in JavaFX for spawning long-running-background-tasks that are preferable to a plain old thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: @jaaBeg16 Updated my answer to show how to do that using the JavaFX concurrency API.

Comment: @Fildor Note that your JavaFX links are out of date (they are for version 2.x). Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) for the current version, e.g. http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXIP546

Comment: @James_D Thanks! I just took the first google hits without paying attention for the version.